# Joomla Subform module

Tags: xml, joomla, module, content-management-system, subform

I am attempting to make a simple subform module that allows for the creating and editing of multiple testimony sections (for website). So, I really just need to take in two text variables, per section; with the ability to add/remove testimonial sections.

Now, I have been searching for a full tutorial on this -- only thing I have found was from the docs: https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type/en

So, I have a couple ideas as to why this isn't working on my end.

First, does the field for the subform go in the EXTENSION xml? That main xml file, the one with the files section, the author, name, config, fieldset, field(s)???

My code is: 
...
...

```
 <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Testimony Section</description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_testimonyfive">mod_testimonyfive.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>mod_testimonyfive.xml</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>

        <fieldset>
              <field name= "params"
                     description= "testimony"
                     type= "subform"
                     label= "testimony"
                     min= "1"
                     max= "12"
                     required= "true"            
                     formsource= "components/com_testimony/testimony.xml"
                     multiple= "true"
                     buttons= "add,remove"
              layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table"
                     groupByFieldset="false"/>
    </fieldset>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Second, that formsource? The only thing in there that I have is an xml file. Do I need more??? That xml file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
      <field name="testimony_visible" type="text" label="Testimony Visible" />
      <field name="testimony_hidden" type="text" label="Testimony Hidden" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it has to be set up like fields -> fieldset -> and then field

```
    <fields name="params">   
        <fieldset name="basic">
        <field name= "params"
                 description= "testimony"
                 type= "subform"
                 label= "testimony"
                 min= "1"
                 max= "12"
                 required= "true"            
                 formsource= "components/com_testimony/testimony.xml"
                 multiple= "true"
                 buttons= "add,remove"
          layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table"
                 groupByFieldset="false"/>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
```